# cant find nonfree module opencv

Tags: opencv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

anyone know where i can download nonfree module for opencv 2.4.8

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209358/cant-find-nonfree-module-opencv/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2015-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

from stack overflow:

sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:xqms/opencv-nonfree
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install libopencv-nonfree-dev

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2015-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0